# GUI problems AFTER login

Tags: intel-graphics, screen

I have been searching for the answer for a while and can't seem to find the same problem anywhere.
It loads fine to the login screen. The guest account works perfectly fine.
Then, when I log into my account, only the bottom left quadrant of my screen turns into my desktop, the rest stays stuck on the login background. I can open any of the folders that I can see, and from there can explore to any directory. But I can't get the task bar to appear. <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> works, and when I use `startx` it seems to start the GUI back up in full screen but it still doesn't have the task bar.

`lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` produced:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation 2nd generation core processor family integrated graphics controller (rev 09) 
Subsystem: Toshiba America info systems device fc30 
Kernel driver in use i915
```

Comment: Please add output of "lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2" to your post.

Comment: A screenshot or photo of screen would help (or a link to it)

Comment: Are you running a virtual machine?

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry for the delay, i'm using this computer on windows right now and have Linux dual booted.
lspci     produced:  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel corporation 2nd generation core processor family integrated graphics controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Toshiba America info systems device fc30
Kernal driver in use i915

Comment: @solsTiCe i'm at work and couldn't get a screen shot, the glare/reflection was too bad for ap icutre to be worth it

Comment: @JREAM no, i have windows and linux dual booted.  I want to get rid of windows and install it virtual in linux but i need to get linux working correctly first.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add information there.

Comment: @Pilot6 oh, sorry. Added.

Comment: @MatthewGoodwin Okay making sure, I have this issue in VMWare when I try to load it full screen (very annoying), So I have to load it half screen, then full screen -- haha.

Answer (score 1):

If guest account works well, then the problem is somewhere in user settings. The easiest way to solve is just create a new user with administrative rights, then transfer all your files to the other home directory. Then delete old user.

Comment: This is actually a very good troubleshooting answer IMO. Id try this.

Comment: This is solution worked, looking into what caused the problem.